# Calling SharedPreferences on AppWidget

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is an issue with calling a sharedPreference value  on an appWidget provider class so i can use it for an update. I have this code which i call on a method in the  appWidget provider class, but it keeps giving me compilation error and that i should create a method for it. this is the code:

```
prefs = getSharedPreference("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

is this a known issue and is there any other way i can pass the value from my configuration class, if this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppWidgetProvider`s are not `Context`s, and therefore do not have access to `getSharedPreferences()`.

There is a standard way to set preferences for AppWidgets, however, which is documented on the Android developer site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring

The basic idea is that you tell the system to launch an activity when the user indicates they want to configure your widget. The configuration screen is obviously an `Activity`, so it has access to `SharedPreferences`, among other things. You then do all your configuring there and manually update the `AppWidget`, whose ID was passed in the start `Intent`. Definitely take a look at the link above to see the detailed steps needed.

Also see http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/appwidget/ExampleAppWidgetConfigure.html for an actual source code example.

Comment: No problem; I still have lots to learn about Android, too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not initializing it using Context. Calling `getSharedPreference` assumes `this.getSharedPreference` which might not be correct.

What class are you calling this within and perhaps you could provide some more source code.

If I were to guess however I would say you could fix is like this:

```
prefs = getContext().getSharedPreference("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or perhaps:

```
prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreference("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or if you have access to a View class:

```
prefs = view.getContext().getSharedPreference("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```